# Automatically creating functions out of function prototypes from header files

Tags: ide, filetype-c++, filetype-c

## Intro

When programming in C and C++ you usually split your function prototypes and actual functions into a `.h`/`.hpp` and `.c`/`.cpp` file. Sadly it's very tedious to transfer the function prototypes from one file to another, and requires opening both files at the same time (or a good memory), as well as a lot of unnecessary typing, especially when changes to the arguments or member names are made.

## Example

`foo.hpp`:

```
int someFunction(int someArgument);

class someClass
{
     public:
     someClass();
     ~someClass();

     int anotherFunction(int anotherArgument);
};
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

int someFunction(int someArgument)
{
    // Code goes here
}

someClass::someClass()
{
    // Code goes here
}

someClass::~someClass()
{
    // Code goes here   
}

int someClass::anotherFunction(int anotherArgument)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

## Question

Is there a way to automatically create and update the functions in `foo.cpp` using the definitions and prototypes in `foo.hpp`?

Answer (score 3):

Whew, this one was fun!

```
:g/.*\n^{/yank A<cr>:bn<cr>pkdd:%s/$/;/<cr>:g/::/d B<cr>A<cr><cr>class <cr>{<cr>};<esc>"BP:%s/[^ ]\+:://<cr>j%jyt(kk$p=ipjA<cr>public:<esc>
```

You can go ahead and map that to a single keystroke in your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-b> :g/.*\n^{/yank A<cr>:bn<cr>pkdd:%s/$/;/<cr>:g/::/d B<cr>A<cr><cr>class <cr>{<cr>};<esc>"BP:%s/[^ ]\+:://<cr>j%jyt(kk$p=ipjA<cr>public:<esc>
```

Note that this assumes that the constructor is the first class method to appear. (I could fix that, but I'd rather keep it simple. Please do mention in a comment if you need that fixed.)

This also assumes that your header file buffer is empty and located directly after your source file buffer.

Step-by-step explanation:

```
:g/.*\n^{/yank A<cr>            Yank all the function definitions (power of g!)
:bn<cr>                         Move to the header file buffer
pkdd                            Put in the function definitions
:%s/$/;/<cr>                    Add semicolons
:g/::/d B<cr>                   Grab the class methods and put them in register B
A<cr><cr>class <cr>{<cr>};<esc> Self-explanatory, add class skeleton
"BP                             Put the class methods in the class
:%s/[^ ]\+:://<cr>              Remove someClass::
j%jyt(kk$p                      Add the actual class name
=ip                             Fix indentation
jA<cr>public:<esc>              Add the `public:' modifier
```

Comment: While this is impressive (I'm rather new to vim, so I'm discovering new things every day!), I'm afraid this isn't at all what I need. Maybe I should look into making my own plugin? It seems like a fun thing to do.

Comment: @Lukas In what way doesn't a mapping in your .vimrc solve the problem? Simply hitting Ctrl-B will then automatically fill out the header file for you. (I should probably make it clear the header file before replacing it with an updated version, but I have to sleep so I might do that later.) A plugin does sound interesting; keep me updated if you decide to make one. And thanks for the interesting challenge to sharpen up my Vim skills! ;)

Comment: This seems to work in the opposite direction from the request: it creates a header file from the .cpp file.

Comment: ... which would also be nice, actually, but I think there are some things that can't be known from the definition: e.g., is the declaration supposed to be `inline`? Are there default arguments? Should the argument names be elided?

Comment: @200_success Ah, you're right (I don't know why I didn't reply to your comment earlier). When I have time, I'll try to edit my answer to go the other way.

Answer (score 3):

The [`:GOTOIMPL`](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/doc/lh-cpp-readme.txt#367) command from [lh-cpp](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) is able to jump to a function definition from its declaration, or to provide a default empty definition in the case none was found.

Some features I can think of:

- The command already understands comments, exception specifications, keywords that shall not be copied (but possibly copied within comments)(`virtual`, `static`, ...).
- The current scope of the function is decoded (namespaces::classes::...) and correctly reported (i.e. it won't prefix with `ns::` if we are within `namespace ns{` or a `using namespace ns;` context.

However:

- Templates are not (yet) understood.
- Function body are to be built manually one after the other -- i.e. I haven't yet took the time to execute :GOTOIMPL on all function declarations that ctags could points me.